# Make postman query param type of boolean

Tags: javascript, postman

I use postman to test my api

```
http://localhost:3000/api/books?disabled=true
```

I want to set disabled=true (or false) and I expect it is a bool

But somehow

```
const {disabled} = req.query;
console.log(typeof disabled) //I get disabled type of string
```

How I set my query param boolean type?

Comment: Have you tired to set disabled to 1 or 0 ?

Comment: It still shows that type of disabled is string

Comment: https://codippa.com/how-to-convert-string-to-boolean-javascript/

Comment: Just asking, won't it work with a boolean? like `let condition = disabled==='true'`?

Comment: You will need to parse it in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the format (query params, JSON body) it is the job of the backend to parse and validate the request.

So even if you send a parameter like “active=true”, it is still a string, this is how the HTTP protocol works.

For more info ---> https://community.getpostman.com/t/how-to-pass-boolean-values-using-postman/1174

Answer (score 0):

```
let disabled = ( req.query.disabled !== 'false' )
```

That should do it. As explained in other answers, HTTP does not natively support any non-string or non-stream types (integers, booleans, etc.). The server is tasked with parsing the meaning from the original request format.

Alternatively, you can also do the following to become more familiar with the intricacies of parsing JSON-based requests.

```
let disabled = JSON.parse(req.query.disabled)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the screen print of passing boolean as query param

[image]

For any reason, if the param returns false, the issues could be that I came across,

1. The key defined in @RequestParam has typo
2. The key defined in @RequestParam has space
3. The key defined in @RequestParam not matching with the key mentioned in postman query param list